# Javascript conditional element span based on the simple math result

Tags: javascript, html

i have a simple script, which calculates for example: eggs based on the inputs/divided by a predefined number with a conditional checkbox to change the divided number. What i would like is to show/span links next to the results output, which are conditinal based on the result.

For example:

- if a result is less than 30, span link 1
- if a result is more than 30 and below 50, span link 2
- if a result is more than 50 and below 70, span link 3
- if a result is more than 70, span link 4

Current layout: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5uqkaavv/1/)

```js
function calculate() {
  var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;
  var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
  var myBox3 = document.getElementById('box3').value;
  var result = document.getElementById('result');
  var divide = (document.getElementById('changeValue').checked ? 35 : 25);
  var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2 * myBox3 / divide;
  result.value = myResult.toFixed(2) + ' eggs';
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="box1" oninput="calculate()" />
<input type="text" id="box2" oninput="calculate()" />
<input type="text" id="box3" oninput="calculate()" />

<input id="result" />

<br />
<br />
<br />

<input type="checkbox" name="changeValue" id="changeValue" />
<label for="changeValue">Divide with 35</label>
```

Any help aprriciated, thanks.

Comment: WHat do you mean by "show/span links next to the results"? There are no spans in your HTML.

Comment: If a result if for example > 30, then include '.innerHTML = '<a href="link-1">link 1</a>';' next to the result input or inside a 'div id="output-links"></div>'

Comment: So use an `if/else if/else` statement. What's the problem?

Comment: writing it all up, i'm very new in javascript

Comment: But so far your are doing fine. So you can complete it by yourself. after you get `myResult` just check  `if(myResult<30).....` and place links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add all the spans to your HTML, but hide them initially. Then use an `if` statement to show the one you want.

```js
function calculate() {
  var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;
  var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
  var myBox3 = document.getElementById('box3').value;
  var result = document.getElementById('result');
  var divide = (document.getElementById('changeValue').checked ? 35 : 25);
  var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2 * myBox3 / divide;
  var links = document.getElementsByClassName("link");
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  var linkToShow;
  if (myResult < 30) {
    linkToShow = 0;
  } else if (myResult < 50) {
    linkToShow = 1;
  } else if (myResult < 70) {
    linkToShow = 2;
  } else {
    linkToShow = 3;
  }
  links[linkToShow].style.display = "inline";
  result.value = myResult.toFixed(2) + ' eggs';
}
```

```css
.link {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="box1" oninput="calculate()" />
<input type="text" id="box2" oninput="calculate()" />
<input type="text" id="box3" oninput="calculate()" />

<input id="result" />
<a class="link" href="link-1">link-1</a>
<a class="link" href="link-2">link-2</a>
<a class="link" href="link-3">link-3</a>
<a class="link" href="link-4">link-4</a>

<br />
<br />
<br />

<input type="checkbox" name="changeValue" id="changeValue" />
<label for="changeValue">Divide with 35</label>
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i've tried to achieve. One question tho - is it possible to display the link after the calculation is done with the current setup? If not, this solution will work just fine.

Comment: That's what this does.

Comment: I ment when the total calculation is finished eg. result value is displayed.

Comment: That's what it does. It displays the link at the same time that it puts `myResult + eggs` in the result field.

Comment: yeah, it's good. Thanks again for a working solution, wish i could vote up :)

Comment: Accepting the answer is better than voting up.